# How to fix z-index of table rows when using transform: scale();

Tags: css, border, css-tables

In a table, I'd like to scale rows with borders on hover. However, the scaled row keeps on being in the background instead of in the foreground. I noticed, that this only happens in tables, not with list-tags (can't change the html though).

I tried a lot of different CSS techniques but none of them seem to work. Like border-collapse, z-index etc. Also targeting the td instead of the tr doesn't work. Edit: using position: absolute breaks the table layout.

```
tr {
  transition: all 0.24s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

tr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  z-index: 10;
}

<normal table html layout table, tbody, tr, td>
```

The screenshot shows the actual result – The hovered row stays behind the other rows hence the thinner borders. The expected result should show the full 1px border in front of the other rows' borders.

http://jsfiddle.net/djpcgmn0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that the row is displayed beneath the other rows in the z-index, but that `border-collapse` prevents the borders in the zoomed row from being drawn correctly.
You can see the problem more clearly if you use `transform: scale(2)` or something when zooming, then the overlap is obvious.

So the solution is to not use `border-collapse: collapse`.
That's basically it. If you also want the borders to look the same as in your fiddle, you will need some more CSS, but that's not the issue.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/  /* not used */
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
  transition: all 1s;
}

tr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

td {
  background: grey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgreen;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

/* new from here */

tr:first-child td, tr:hover td {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgreen;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 data cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 data cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 data cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 data cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 data cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 data cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 data cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 data cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 data cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```